# How to match the line begin?

Tags: compiler-construction, lex

I was writing the `cat(1)` utility with lex.
When I consider how to implement option `-n`, i.e. number every line.
but I have to write something like this:

```
^. {
printf("%8d  ", ++lino);
ECHO;
}
```

I know the end of line(EOL) could matched use anchor `$` and `\n`, so I wonder if there's something alike to match the begin of line(BOL) anchor, so I don't have to use the ECHO;

Comment: Using something like `lex` to create a simple `cat` utility is overkill and probably not very efficient and definitely will make things more complicated. Why not simply read the file into a large buffer, and extract lines from the buffer and print them to `stdout`? Then it's very easy to handle line numbers, just keep a counter and print the number before each line.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm not going to use this `cat`, not really. I just try to figure out how lex works. I'm diving into something like compier-craft stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I agree with the comment by [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) that `lex` is *not* the tool for implementing `cat`. The rest of this answer is in the spirit of explaining a bit about `lex`.)

1. The provided lex program will not work if there are empty lines in the input, because `^.` does not match an empty line. (In lex, `.` does not match a newline character.) So a reasonably minimal (f)lex input file would be:

   ```
   %options noyywrap noinput nounput
   %%
     int lino = 0;
   ^(.|\n)    { printf("%8d   %c", ++lino, *yytext); }
   ```

   Here, I just print out the matched token in the `printf`, which is the equivalent to using `ECHO`. So it does not really "eliminate" the `ECHO`.
2. (f)lex rules must match at least one character. So it wouldn't really be possible for a pattern to consist only of `$`, any more than it would be possible for a pattern to consist only of `^` (which is a BOL anchor). In that sense, the answer to your question is simply "no".
3. A more easily-understood (and probably more efficient) solution is to actually match each line. This solution *never* uses `ECHO`, not even in the default rule, so I've told flex to not generate a default rule:

   ```
   %options noyywrap noinput nounput nodefault
   %%
     int lino = 0;
   .*\n?    { printf("%8d   %s", ++lino, yytext); }
   ```

   That's not quite perfect, because it will truncate lines which contain a NUL character. (That is, the `printf` will effectively truncate the line; the line will be parsed correctly.) To fix it, it's necessary to use `fwrite` instead of `printf`:

   ```
   %options noyywrap noinput nounput nodefault
   %%
     int lino = 0;
   .*\n?    { printf("%8d   %s", ++lino);
              fwrite(yytext, 1, yyleng, yyout); }
   ```

   The newline is made optional (`\n?`) in case the last line of the file is not terminated with a newline. Because (f)lex patterns never match zero characters, that rule is actually equivalent to the more precise but clunkier regular expression `.*\n|.+`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's just awesome. But there still one question in my head, what if the line goes too large, just image that occasionally invoke this cat again a big binary file which may contains very long line?

Comment: @oxnz: Unless you require `yytext` to be an array (which you shouldn't do; the feature only exists for legacy), then (f)lex will continue to reallocate the token buffer as necessary. If it runs out of memory trying to do that, it will throw a fatal error by invoking the macro `YY_FATAL_ERROR`, which by default causes an error message to be printed to `stderr` followed by a call to `exit()` with a non-zero argument. Although that's unlikely, as would be an attempt to print a big binary file with line numbers, it is yet another reason not to build `cat` with (f)lex.